# ASP.NET CustomValidator not firing the event

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, telerik, customvalidator

I have a page with a drop-down list (Telerik RadComboBox) control to validate.

I have put a CustomValidator to verify that the user has selected something from the list.
Then there is a LinkButton to submit the selection.

This is the CustomValidator:

```
<asp:CustomValidator
ID="CustomValidator1"
runat="server"
ClientValidationFunction="validateCombo" ValidateEmptyText="true"
ErrorMessage="You must select an item with even value"
ValidationGroup="defGroup">
```

this is the LinkButton:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="LnkInsertOrder" runat="server" Text="Inserisci Ordine" OnClick="LnkInsertOrder_Click" CausesValidation="true" ValidationGroup="defGroup" CssClass="btn btn-lg btn-info"> </asp:LinkButton>
```

and here is the client side function I'm using for test:

```
function validateCombo(source, args) {
            alert('validateCombo'); //is never shown!
            args.IsValid = false;   //fake validation...
}
```

**validateCombo** is never called, as I never see the alert, and even if I try to call manually from the js console the .net framework function **Page_ClientValidate("defGroup")**, it always returns true, and the alert is not shown.

When I press the link button it performs a postback and the property **Page.isValid** is true.

I'm trying to stop the postback when the user press the link button if all the validators of the defGroup validation group are not valid.

Comment: It works here. Maybe there is a JavaScript error somewhere else on the page. If there is, PostBack will not be prevented by the Validator. Check your console.

Comment: already checked, no errors! So if it works on you, it means the code I've posted is correct, it should works this way... It's 3 hrs I'm stuck on it without seeing the light

Comment: Delete your browser cache memory ?

Comment: A post back occur at the same time the validation takes place ?

Comment: @Antoine done, nothing change. When I click the LinkButton it immediately fires a postback, validation seems to be ignored. But why even if I call the page validation manually from the console it completely ignores the CustomValidator??!

Comment: Really ???? I was about to say there is something in your page_load() that cancel everything.... but now i'd say restart your whole computer and hope it is solved.

Comment: Ha seriously i think it's because there is 2 post back when you think there is only one, put a break point in your page load and see how many time the compiler goes through it

Comment: @Giox. Yes your code works. I copied it to a aspx page and it fired the Validator. (I did had to close the Validator `ValidationGroup="defGroup" />` but I assume this is a copy-paste mistake here on SO, otherwise my test site would not compile)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Discovered that also Page_Validators list on the client is empty (it should contain all the asp.net validators), and it has guide me to the "solution": .net 4.5 has an 'incompatibility' of some kind when you put a **ScriptManager** and you use also jQuery >1.9... or maybe I have to add the js libs using ScriptResourceMapping in Global.asax

BTW to fix it, simply use the old validation style adding a key setting in web.config:

```
<appSettings>
 <add key="ValidationSettings:UnobtrusiveValidationMode" value="None" />
</appSettings>
```

it sounds crazy to me, but when I've added this line everything has started to work

Answer (score -2):

Trying Adding your ControlToValidate in your CustomValidator:

Comment: `ControlToValidate` is not needed for a `CustomValidator` to work.

Answer (score -3):

you are missing **Missing   "ControlToValidate" property inside CustomValidator** add that or you can add a key setting in web.config file to make it working.